# Facebook FQL query on specific fanpage always returns empty result set

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm trying to determine if a connected user (with the user_likes permission given) has liked one specific fanpage. I'm running the following FQL query:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id = FANPAGE_ID
```

This always returns me an empty set:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

However when I run the query without the AND clause:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me()
```

Facebook returns an array of page_id's that always contains the FANPAGE_ID id from the first query.

Any ideas? Is this a bug? The code used to work.